# Sending email through Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
fromaddr = "sender mail id"
toaddr = "receiver mail id"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Test"
body = "Test mail"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
filename = "foo.txt"
attachment = open(r"F:\python\foo.txt", "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
msg.attach(part)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

this script is working fine when I running on my local system but on running on private network its giving me a error.

OSError: [Win Error 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into if you have access from your private network to `smtp.gmail.com` on port 587

The private network admin may have setup the network to block outbound traffic on port 587

Try:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

If you get an unreachable network error its definitely a network issue.